# Bootstrap 3 datepicker and .net

Tags: jquery, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have been trying to incorporate Datepicker into a visual basic application.  I am unable to get the calendar to popup when clicking inside my text box.  I have installed Bootstrap 3 and I have downloaded bootstrap-datepicker.js and datepicker.css.  bootstrap-datapicker.js is sitting in my /Scripts folder (along with the bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, and the jquery-1/10.2*.js family of files) and datepicker.css is sitting in my /Content folder (along with all the bootstrap*.css files).

Below is the code I am executing.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you, Jonathan

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title id="titleTag"><%: Page.Title %> 401(k) Account</title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<link runat="server" id="StyleLink1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site_vsta.css" />
<link runat="server" id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Site.css"/>
<link runat="server" id="Link2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/datepicker.css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
    <div class="container">
        <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextbox" runat="server" CssClass="m-wrap span12 date form_datetime" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var dp = $('#<%=DateTextbox.ClientID%>');
    dp.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
        language: "tr"
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
});
  </script>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've had similar problems with jQuery UI and ended up removing the `<asp:ScriptReference>` for jquery and using a standard `<script>` reference to fix it.  I don't know what value the asp:ScriptReference adds.  You also might just need to move your reference to bootstrap-datepicker.js below the asp:ScriptManager.  The order that the scripts get loaded matters.  Use F12 in the brower to see if there are any errors and include that in your question.

Comment: [Here is a simplified demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amdhr7sa/)  Try simplifying your references for troubleshooting in order to identify the problem.

Comment: Moving the reference to bootstrap-datepicker.js below the scriptmanager fixed my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: My memory isn't great on the specifics, but I seem to recall either moment.js or prettify.js being needed to make mine work.

Answer (score 0):

Move the reference to bootstrap-datepicker.js below the `<asp:ScriptManager>` block.